# How to enable Nautilus mounted remote shares in a file system dialog

Tags: networking, nautilus, share

I can see the remote share from nautilus and browse to it. I want to access that share from another application in this case, Eclipse - which is using the standard open file dialog.

Is there a convenient way I can do this from Nautilus? I cannot find that share anyway on the file system, mnt or media... is it somewhere? How do I put it somewhere if it is now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the share is mounted it should be in Media/mount-point, you can also find it in `~/.gvfs`.

Comment: you got a typo there man, the directory is .gvfs

Comment: thanks - I found it at ~/.gvfs - be nice if this directory wasn't hidden :)

Answer (score 1):

[SMBNetFS](http://packages.ubuntu.com/de/maverick/smbnetfs) is a nice tool based on FUSE that allows mounting of samba shares in any directory in the user's home. Shares are then accessible from all applications.